# "tiny-miners" tag: "tiny-miner" already exists. Could we add "tiny-miners" to the tag list

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I came across [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/290164/what-determines-super-drill-length) question about the mobile game "tiny-miners", however the tag the user has used is "tiny-miner". If I search for "tiny-miner" in the [google play store](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=tiny%20miner) the number one hit is "tiny-miners", which is the game the question is asked about. 
The tag "tiny-miner" is therefore misleading.

UPDATE:  Seems I didn't pay enough attention and there is actually a game called "tiny-miner", but it is still not the game referenced to in the question.

Therefore I am asking the following question: Could we add a tag "tiny-miners"?

Comment: Just a heads up: [Tiny Miner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.qube.tinyminer) and [Tiny Miners](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aboutfun.tinyminers) are two different games.

Comment: Thank you, seems I had not paid enough attention. Updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the tag up on that question, it is now [tiny-miners](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tiny-miners) instead of [tiny-miner](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tiny-miner).

Note that a tag cannot exist without at least one question, so the latter tag will be removed in about 24 hours or so. If anyone needs to recreate it for questions about that game, they can do so at the time of asking. It only takes [300 rep](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) to create new tags.

Comment: I don't think the system will allow mere mortals to create a [tag:tiny-miner] tag when there is already a [tag:tiny-miners] tag.

Comment: @amaranth - I thought that only affected renames when it came to inserting dashes. Oh well. Just ping me or one of the other mods if it becomes a problem and we'll create it :).